# How to create helper for Netzke component?

Tags: netzke

I want to create helper method for netzke component.

Because now I put that in netzke component class.

And it's look ugly code for me I want to change it. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now I have found answer for this. Its very very easy.**

`I use module and call it directly. Sorry for stupid question :P`